# Windows 10 Updates Always fail with message "Could not complete updates, reverting changes"

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, updates

My PC has been doing this for probably a month or more. It gets an update notification every day. When I install the update, it proceeds normally, but fails right at the end and says "reverting changes, do not turn off your PC". The update notification then disappears until the next day, presumably while it downloads the update again.

I have tried several fixes posted online such as deleting the update cache and restarting the update service, but they haven't helped. **What I would like to do is look at some sort of log file and figure out exactly why it's failing.** My PC has a pretty complicated configuration, so it could be anything.

I'm dual booting, with 2 versions of windows 10, 1 is enterprise, and the other is pro. They are on different physical drives. The PRO version is never updated or connected to the internet. The enterprise version is what I use most of the time, and it's what I want to update.

During the update the machine has to restart. This brings it to the windows OS selection screen; which I thought might cause problems, but when I select the enterprise edition OS, the update continues as you'd expect, up until the point where it fails.

I also must admit that I have a habit of disabling windows services that look unnecessary (for example windows store or xbox related stuff). That does sometimes cause issues when I kill something that I shouldn't have so just throwing it out there.

I tried using the  Get-WindowsUpdateLog command in powershell to generate a log file, but it's extremely long and I don't know exactly what to look for in it. I see some failures but those might just be temporary network issues or whatever.

**Edit:** [Here](https://pastebin.com/4YSzC53P) are the most recent entries from Get-WindowsUpdateLog after a failed reboot. I can post more if needed.

**Edit2:** When I got back to the update settings screen after a failed update, it shows the error code (0x800f0922).

**Edit3:** Here's my partition table:
[image: partition table]
I'm fairly sure MAIN_OS (the OS I'm trying to update) is the primary.

Comment: Try unplugging all USB devices (unless absolutely required, like keyboard). This fixed the same problem for me and some ither people I know. After the successful update, plug them back in.

Comment: @Aganju Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Drew What is the size of system reserved partition ? Which OS is default OS ? Any extra drivers you use ? what is the version and build number of both OSes ? What exactly is that update about ??

Comment: @Madhubala I'm not sure which partition is the system reserved one so I've posted the whole table. I believe the OS i'm trying to update (MAIN_OS) is the default, but if there's a way to double check I'll do it. I'm an engineer so I have a lot of hardware with special drivers but none of it is currently connected. MAIN_OS build is 19041.572. Not sure about the SECURE_OS.

Comment: It looks like I don't have a system reserved partition. I'm not sure how that happened.

Comment: If you need update your windows 10 enterprise device update to the latest version, I would suggest you download Windows Update Assistant from the following link and have a try. The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @Sunny That seems to have worked, thank you! Hopefully I won't have to do that every time. You should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Drew  Glad to hear that the information if helpful to you. I have posted it as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need update your windows 10 enterprise device update to the latest version, I would suggest you download Windows Update Assistant from the following link and have a try. The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10.

[microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)